# Вывод записей по похожим меткам Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Пытаюсь отсортировать вывод записей по их меткам, проблема в том что это произвольные типы записей.
Вот такой код используется для вывода всех этих записей:

```
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'event',
        'posts_per_page' => 20,
    );
    $q = new WP_Query($args); if ( $q->have_posts() ) : while ( $q->have_posts() ) : $q->the_post(); 

    <div>
        <?php the_title(); ?>
    </div>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Но как сделать сортировку по их похожим меткам.
Например если у записи метка "TR" то выводятся только записи с данной меткой и т.д.

Comment: Во первых "если у записи метка "TR" то выводятся только записи" это не сортировка. а фильтр или выборка. А во вторых ничего придумывать  ненужно - страница метки есть дефолтная фича ВП. [Шаблон  tag.php](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2#.D0.9E.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.B1.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B6.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.82.D0.BA.D0.B8)